# Vertically align menu in CSS

Tags: html, menu, css

Im stuck in creating the following menu. Cant get it to center. Seems like `img` inside `span` is breaking the display.

**DESIRED RESULT:**
[image: menu]

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="rounded-cats" class="cleardiv">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
            </span>
            <strong>
                Category name
            </strong>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
            </span>
            <strong>
                Category name
            </strong>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
            </span>
            <strong>
                Category name
            </strong>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
            </span>
            <strong>
                Category name
            </strong>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
            </span>
            <strong>
                Category name
            </strong>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
            </span>
            <strong>
                Category name
            </strong>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
            </span>
            <strong>
                Category name
            </strong>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
#rounded-cats {
    text-align: center;
    //display: table;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%
}
#rounded-cats li {
    //margin-bottom: 20px;
    //height: 190px;
    display: inline;
}
#rounded-cats span {
    background: #c7c7c7;
    width: 112px;
    height: 112px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#rounded-cats span img {
    display: inline !important  
}
#rounded-cats a:hover span {
    background: #7c6eb0 
}
#rounded-cats a:hover {
    color: #7c6eb0  
}
#rounded-cats img {
    margin: auto;
    display: block; 
}
```

**JSFIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/gtux2snu/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div

Comment: FYI `//display: table;` is not a CSS comment, you should use this: `/* display: table; */`

Comment: [here?](http://jsfiddle.net/gtux2snu/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gtux2snu/3/)

I have made changes to `#rounded-cats li` and `#rounded-cats span img` styles.

```
#rounded-cats {
    text-align: center;
    //display: table;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%
}
#rounded-cats li {
    //margin-bottom: 20px;
    //height: 190px;
    display: inline-block;
    width:150px;//added some width to each li
    float:left;//floated elements left
    text-align:left;//aligned category name with image
    padding:20px;//add padding so it looks good and separated.
}
#rounded-cats span {
    background: #c7c7c7;
    width: 112px;
    height: 112px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#rounded-cats span img {
    display: inline !important;
    margin-top:18px;//centered img inside circle
}
#rounded-cats a:hover span {
    background: #7c6eb0 
}
#rounded-cats a:hover {
    color: #7c6eb0  
}
#rounded-cats img {
    margin: auto;
    display: block; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtux2snu/16/)

```
li{
display: table;
}
span{
display: table-cell;
}
```

I now got exactly what you want. Just like you want it. Take a look at the fiddle and let me know if this is what you want.

UPDATED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make you `li` `inline-block` and give the `span` some padding :

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e5mhopm6/)

```css
#rounded-cats li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And the span :

```css
#rounded-cats span {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 21px; /* to get a span width and height of 112px */
    /* code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use `float: left` to `li` elements and clear `float` after `5n`:

```css
#maintCont {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#rounded-cats {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}
#rounded-cats li {
    //margin-bottom: 20px;
    //height: 190px;
    display: inline;
}
#rounded-cats span {
    background: #c7c7c7;
    width: 112px;
    height: 112px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#rounded-cats span img {
    display: inline !important
}
#rounded-cats a:hover span {
    background: #7c6eb0
}
#rounded-cats a:hover {
    color: #7c6eb0
}
#rounded-cats img {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
#rounded-cats > li {
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
}
#rounded-cats > li:nth-child(5n) {
    clear: left;
    padding-left: 65px;
}
```

```html
<div id="maintCont">
    <ul id="rounded-cats" class="cleardiv">
        <li> <a href="#">
   <span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
   </span>
   <strong>
    Category name
   </strong>
  </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">
   <span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
   </span>
   <strong>
    Category name
   </strong>
  </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">
   <span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
   </span>
   <strong>
    Category name
   </strong>
  </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">
   <span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
   </span>
   <strong>
    Category name
   </strong>
  </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">
   <span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
   </span>
   <strong>
    Category name
   </strong>
  </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">
   <span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
   </span>
   <strong>
    Category name
   </strong>
  </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">
   <span>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
   </span>
   <strong>
    Category name
   </strong>
  </a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Din't get is ok or not? Tell me or i delete this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should do the trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/gtux2snu/15/

I added a `div` element to wrap the `li` content with relative position so the category name can be absolute positioned to the bottom. Also set the `span` circle to relative and the `img` to absolute with `top: 50%` and a negative half height `margin-top`.

```
<a href="#">
     <div class="cats-wrap">
         <span>
             <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
         </span>
         <strong>
               Category name
         </strong>
    </div>
</a>
```

I changed this part of CSS:

```
#rounded-cats span {
    background: #c7c7c7;
    width: 112px;
    height: 112px;
    border-radius: 50%;

    position: relative; /* To contain the absolute positioned img */

    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#rounded-cats span img {
    display: inline !important;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; /* align all the img 50% top */
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -35px; 
    margin-top: -35px; /* Half the img height so img is centered */

}
#rounded-cats .cats-wrap{ /* Wrapper element set to relative */
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 140px; /* Add some height to the wrapper so the category name can fit */ 
}
#rounded-cats strong{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; /* Category is aligned to the absolute bottom */
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    margin: auto; /* To center the category name */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed some issues in your css and you could simply do that like this:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zzftk3nL/)

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
    margin:0;
}
#rounded-cats {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
#rounded-cats li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
}
#rounded-cats span {
    background: #c7c7c7;
    width: 112px;
    height: 112px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#rounded-cats span:before {
    height: 100%;
    content:" ";
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
#rounded-cats span img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#rounded-cats a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#rounded-cats a:hover span {
    background: #7c6eb0
}
#rounded-cats a:hover {
    color: #7c6eb0
}
```

```html
<ul id="rounded-cats" class="cleardiv">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span><img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" /></span>Category name</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span><img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" /></span>Category name</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span><img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" /></span>Category name</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span><img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" /></span>Category name</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span><img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" /></span>Category name</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span><img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" /></span>Category name</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><span><img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" /></span>Category name</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code pen http://jsfiddle.net/dfrierson2/gtux2snu/19/
I seperated the elements into div's for centering, and I used lists for the inline display.

```
ul li {
     list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
 }

li {
display: inline-block;
}

li a {
color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
#rounded {
    text-align: center;
    //display: table-cell;

    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 1em 0;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;


}
#rounded img {
    margin-bottom: 55px;
    position: relative;
}




#rounded-cats  {
    background: #c7c7c7;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    text-align: center;
    border-box: sizing;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

<ul>
<li>
<div id="rounded-cats">
        <div id="rounded">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
        <a href="#">    
            <strong>
                Category name
            </strong>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
    </li>
    <li>
<div id="rounded-cats">
        <div id="rounded">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
        <a href="#">    
            <strong>
                Category name
            </strong>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
        </li>
<li>
<div id="rounded-cats">
        <div id="rounded">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
        <a href="#">    
            <strong>
                Category name
            </strong>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
    </li>
    <li>
<div id="rounded-cats">
        <div id="rounded">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
        <a href="#">    
            <strong>
                Category name
            </strong>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
    </li>
    <li>
<div id="rounded-cats">
        <div id="rounded">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
        <a href="#">    
            <strong>
                Category name
            </strong>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
    </li>
    <li>
<div id="rounded-cats">
        <div id="rounded">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
        <a href="#">    
            <strong>
                Category name
            </strong>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
    </li>
    <li>
<div id="rounded-cats">
        <div id="rounded">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/70" height="70" />
        <a href="#">    
            <strong>
                Category name
            </strong>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```